# Append Value in Tuple

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

Can anyone please tell me how i can append value in `tuple` from my `favBt` Function.
I've tried from two different ways but same error?

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

1. appendData.tupple.append(values)
2. appendData.tupple.append(url,image)
```

[image]

```
var objects : [(String, String)] = [
                ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h30Bx4Klxg","1.jpg"),
                ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ij_0p_6qTss","2.jpg"),
                ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJtDXIazrMo","3.jpg"),
                ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H202k7KfZL0","4.jpg"),
                ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGyEd0aKWZE","5.jpg"),
                ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtKZKl7Bgu0","6.jpg"),
                ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SYlLi5djz0","7.jpg")]

    func favBt(sender: UIButton){

            var btn : NSInteger
            btn = sender.tag as NSInteger

            let (url,image) = objects[btn]

            let values = (url, image)
            print(values)

            let appendData = ViewController()

            appendData.tupple.append(values)

            print(appendData.tupple[btn])

          }

    In my ViewController Class

    class ViewController: UIViewController{
       var tuple : [(String, String)]?
    }
```

Comment: `let appendData = ViewController()` creates a new ViewController (probably not what you want) where the `tupple` property is `nil` (because it is optional). Use `let appendData = self`.

Comment: Your problem is here: `let appendData = ViewController()`. This is not the same instance that you will use later. IB instantiates another one. // Also, don't make an array an optional, it's semantically wrong to make a collection nullable.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to. var tupple : [(String, String)] = []
When o call function first time it append value in this tupple but when i call function second time it gives error  fatal error: Array index out of range
Can you tell me what i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let appendData = ViewController()` I Create this out side from function.

Replace it `var tuple : [(String, String)]?`

to

`var tuple : [(String, String)] = []`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the "tuple" variable. You can try the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
   var tuple : [(String, String)]?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.tuple = [(String, String)]()
   }
}
```